# jQuery - .on('click' ... ) does not work on already existing elements while working on dynamically created ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dynamic, click

javascript:

```
$('body').on('click', '.deleteButton > a', function() {
    alert('pop');
    return false;
});
```

html:

```
<div class="deleteButton">
    <a href="#">✖</a>
</div>
```

This type of binding the click event is working well on newly created elements (via .clone and .prepend), but not working on already existing ones.

But using .click() instead of .on() is working on already existing elements while not working on newly created.

Is there any way to bind a click event both on new and already existing elements with one line?

Comment: should be just fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5avtsqnz/1/

Answer (score 0):

Well you can just have a look at the fiddle [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5avtsqnz/2/)

```
$('body').on('click', '.deleteButton > a', function () {});
```

What you need to do is to attach the event to the body instead of the classes or id's. Doing this will bind your event to the body and in return all the body elements will automatically  bind to this event.

Comment: yes, it attaches the event to body, when you do `$('body').on(event, selector, function(){});`. I meant when you do `$(selector).click(function(){})`,  it will attach the event to each selector separatly.

Comment: Okay then, the error is somewhere in the rest part of the code :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine. But still you can try this one. It also worked.

```
$('.deleteButton > a').on('click', function () {
alert('pop');
return false;
});
```

Comment: Well, tried all the solutions in this thread. Here is what i've found:

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){ 
$('body').on('click', '.deleteButton > a', function() {
alert('pop'); return false; 
}); 
}); 

makes alert('pop') work on new elements only, while

$('.deleteButton > a').on('click', function () { 
alert('pop'); return false; 
}); 

allows to recieve a 'pop alert' only from already existing elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $('body').on('click', '.deleteButton > a', function() {
                alert('pop');
                return false;
            });
            });
```

Hope this will help you.

check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/83auy700/)